# c# bitarray index of positive bits

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I have a c# BitArray that is fairly large (500,000) in length, and I am trying to get the index of all the positive bits set in the array. currently I am achieving this by:

```
public int[] GetIndexesForPositives()
{
    var idIndexes = new int[GetPositiveCount + 1];
    var idx = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            if (Get(i))
            {
                idIndexes[idx++] = i;
            }
        }
    return idIndexes;
}
```

I create an empty array of the size of known positive bits, then i lopp over the bitarray and add the index value to the return array.

This means I have to perform 500,000 loops over the array and its not exactly fast. (takes around 15ms).

I know the BitArray uses an integer array under the covers (i used it to write the GetPositiveCount function - via an alogrithm I got off stack), I wonder if there is an algorythm to do this aswell?

Comment: And that algorithm would not need a loop with 500K iterations? (My point: even if this isn't fast enough, you can try changing anything *except* the loop).

Comment: perhaps recursive is the wrong word, i'm simply trying to avoid looping 500k times. id much rather loop over the underlying integer array in the BitArray class, which would involve less loops.

Comment: If this is not a premature optimization you can use loop unrolling and reduce your loops to 125.000. But what do you gain from this optimization? I presume fairly nothing.

Comment: @AaronHS Perhaps you meant that you were **iterating** through the set.

Comment: @PVitt thanks for the suggestion of unrolling. ive done it and it has made a difference. ill post it as an answer unless you'd like to? regarding premature optimization, with respect, i dont think its fair to question motives without knowing a bit more background :)

Comment: @AaronHS: And I think is is not fair to ask questions without giving background information and leaving people guessing around ;)

Comment: Is your Get(i) actually <BitArray>.Get(i)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to get a int array underlying the BitArray, this should provide much better performance:

Assuming you don't know the number of bits that are set:

```
public static int[] GetIndexesForPositives()
{
    var idIndexes = new List<int>();
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = data.GetType().GetField("m_array", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    int[] values = field.GetValue(data) as int[];

    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        int _i = values[i];
        if (_i != 0)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                if ((_i & (1 << j)) != 0)
                {
                    idIndexes.Add(i * 32 + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return idIndexes.ToArray();
}
```

If you do know the number of bits that are set you can do this instead:

```
public static int[] GetIndexesForPositives(int length)
{
    var idIndexes = new int[length];
    var idx = 0;
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = data.GetType().GetField("m_array", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    int[] values = field.GetValue(data) as int[];

    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        int _i = values[i];
        if (_i != 0)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                if ((_i & (1 << j)) != 0)
                {
                    idIndexes[idx++] = i * 32 + j;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My tests have these two working faster than your method, even the one that doesn't know how large the return array will be in the first place.

My results tested using a random BitArray of 50million records:

```
1) 25001063 records found in 50000000, took 1415.5752ms
2) 25001063 records found in 50000000, took 1099.67ms
3) 25001063 records found in 50000000, took 1045.6862ms
4) 25001063 records found in 50000000, took 745.7762ms"

1) is your code but using an arraylist instead of using some `GetPositiveCount` to get the output length.
2) is your code
3) is my (revised) first example
4) is my (revised) second example
```

edit: furthermore it is worth pointing out that this is a problem that could really benefit from being made multi-threaded. Break the ByteArray up into 4 parts and there you have 4 threads that could run checking the data at once.

Edit: I know this is already accepted but here's another bit you can do to improve performance if you know that most of the time your list will be very sparse:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
     if (_i == 0)
         break;
     if ((_i & (1)) != 0)
     {
         idIndexes.Add(i * 32 + j);
     }
     _i = _i >> 1;
 }
```

it is slightly slower when the list is >40% or more populated however if you know the list is always going to be 10% 1s and 90% 0s then this will run even faster for you.

Comment: for this to work i'd have to first convert the bitarray to a byte array though wouldnt i?

Comment: BitArray from the BCL uses an array of ints internally, not bytes. It is called "m_array", and @AaronHS you can get it with reflection

Comment: yes, am aware. this is how i implemented the GetPositiveCountmethod. reflected copied and extended as it was sealed:(

Comment: just an fyi, converting the underlying int[] to a byte[] and then executing the above, was half the speed.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use m_array rather than a byte array, performance while slightly better, remains much the same as I already had the byte array to begin with.

Comment: fantastic. went from 15ms (17k of positives in 500k) down to 4ms

Comment: Good to hear, the major performance improvement is from comparing for non-zero integers and then using the bit shift to compare. There' a noticeable overhead on the .Get() call which is why I avoid doing it. I am unsure if there would be much further room for improvement over the above. Just wondering though, did you end up using the ArrayList method or the known length method? I am just wondering if you have a performance bottleneck in your GetPositiveCount method as that would likely be the only point left

Comment: the getpositive count takes around 1ms and strangely the list<int> compared to the int[] is pretty much identical... played around with a few more optimizations and it running at 1ms now for 17k of positives in 500k. love your work

Answer (score 6):

If you can swap out the BitArray from the BCL in favour of a "roll your own", you can do better than that. Here's a few things you can do:

1. Skip chunks of 64 that have no bits set
2. For chunks of 64 that do have bits, only enumerate the 1-bits instead of all bits using `x & (x - 1)` and your favourite fast 2log found [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup) (using the naive 64-step method won't give any kind of speedup)
3. Keep an extra bitarray which stores, for each 64bit chunk, whether it is nonzero. Apply the technique from bullet 2 to *that* bitarray to skip whole ranges of zero's in one go.
4. Apply bullet 3 recursively for gigantic bitarrays

All four of these only help if the bitarray is expected to be sparse, and the worst case is still O(n) if it isn't sparse. If bullet 3 is applied until the top is a single ulong then it can in O(1) determine whether the entire bitarray is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
public int[] GetIndexesForPositives()
{
    var idIndexes = new LinkedList<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            if (Get(i))
            {
                idIndexes.Add(i);
            }
        }
    return idIndexes.ToArray();
}
```

If this is still not acceptable (because you walk the indizes again while doing ToArray) just use the same size for your result array and return the length of found indizes:

```
public int GetIndexesForPositives(out int[] indizes)
{
    indizes = new int[Length];
    var idI = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            if (Get(i))
            {
                indizes[idI++] = i;
            }
        }
    return idI;
}
```

Depending on if you really need all the indizes or only parts you might even consider something like this (but it will be less performant if you need every part - do some profiling yourself please):

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetIndexesForPositives()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            if (Get(i))
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
}
```

this is assuming that your Get(i) is doing it's job and that your array is immutable.

Comment: unfortunately the first is a little slower and the second is the same. the lazily evaluated one is not really going to make a difference due to the fact im always doing the entire array

Comment: Sorry. I guess that's because you allready know the count of the array - maybe you can change this to create the array and the count in one go - this way my second solution should be faster because it does both.

Comment: BTW: if it is ok for you to go with the collection/list you can try doing the first without the ToArray - but I guess you won't get it much quicker than what you had

Answer (score 1):

You're fairly stuck with iterating 500,000 times.  Intuitively: if every bit is set then you'll need to produce an array with 500,000 elements.  You can reduce the number of outer iterations by a factor of 8 or 32 by accessing the underlying byte or int but then you'll still have to iterate the bits.  Even a lookup table with 256 elements for every possible byte value won't help since you have to add the bit index.

However, if you have a lot of zero bits (sure hope you do) then an optimization is to simply adjust the loop counter by 8 or 32 if the underlying byte/int is 0.  Since you know Get() will return 0.  Also, use a List<> to avoid the expense of GetPostitiveCount.

Completely eliminating the need for this array and lazily retrieving the next bit set to 1 would be by far the best approach.

Comment: thanks, yes the chunking and bit shifting made a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Seph in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7415891/264022 is really nice, but it can be done a bit faster yet.

1. First count the number of bits
2. Unroll the inner loop (check 4 bits at a time)
   2b. Make a construct, so that the JIT makes a jump table instead of a bunch IFs (This becomes the only unpredictable branch)
3. Use safe C# pointer magic to avoid out of bounds checks

Result is about 3-4x faster than the already fast version from @Seph.

```
  public static int[] GetIndexesForPositives(ulong[] _array)
  {
     var thisArray = _array;

     var c2 = 0ul;
     for (var i = 0; i < thisArray.Length; i++)
     {
        var v = thisArray[i];
        //from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel
        v = v - ((v >> 1) & (ulong)~(ulong)0/3);                           // temp
        v = (v & (ulong)~(ulong)0/15*3) + ((v >> 2) & (ulong)~(ulong)0/15*3);      // temp
        v = (v + (v >> 4)) & (ulong)~(ulong)0/255*15;                      // temp
        var c = (ulong) (v * ((ulong) ~(ulong) 0 / 255)) >> (sizeof(ulong) - 1) * 8; // count
        c2 += c;
     }
     if (c2 == 0) return Array.Empty<int>();

     var idIndexes = new int[c2];
     ref var idxref = ref idIndexes[0];
     for (var i = 0; i < thisArray.Length; i++)
     {
        var v = thisArray[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < 64; j += 4)
        {
           if (v == 0)
              break;
           var b = ((byte)v) & 0b1111;
           var actualIndex = i * 64 + j;
           switch (b)
           {
           case 0: break;
           case 0b001:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b010:
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b011:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b100:
              idxref = (actualIndex + 2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b101:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b110:
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b111:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1000: 
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1001:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1010:
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1011:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1100:
              idxref = (actualIndex + 2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1101:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1110:
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;
           case 0b1111:
              idxref = (actualIndex);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+1);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+2);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              idxref = (actualIndex+3);
              idxref = ref Unsafe.Add(ref idxref, 1);
              break;

           }

           v >>= 4;
        }
     }
     return idIndexes;
  }
```